# Why does 'Per Page' look like a button on our StackExchange interface?

Tags: bug, design

5 15 50 per page

Looks like 4 buttons to me. I accidentally clicked 'per page' and nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: That's odd, other Stack Exchange sites don't do that with the label, either

Comment: This is a bug indeed. +1 for not using the confused Jackie Chan face. I'll fix it.

Comment: @BenBrocka Actually, part of them have this label, others do not - I described it in this question over at physics meta [Can the label “per page” on lists made look different than the links next to it?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/can-the-label-per-page-on-lists-made-look-different-than-the-links-next-to-it). There is also a related, similar problem with the "next" link to the left of these buttons. It's roughly the inverse of this one.